# Redundancy of reflexive property

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why isn't the reflexive property redundant we defining an equivalence class? If $x \sim y$, then $y \sim x$ by the symmetric property. Using the transitive property we can deduce that $x \sim x$.

Comment: What if there is no $y$ with $x \sim y$?

Answer (score 3):

A counterexample: let $R$ be the relation on the set $X=\{ a, b , c\}$ defined by
$$R= \{ (a,a), (b,b) , (a,b), (b,a)\}$$
This is not an equivalence relation because it is not reflexive ($(c,c) \notin R$!). By the way, $R$ is clearly symmetric and transitive.

Here what fails is the existence of some element $x \in X$ satisfying $(c,x) \in R$. Such an element would allow you to use the argument $cRx, xRc \Rightarrow cRc$; but there is none, so that we can't say anything.

Answer (score 1):

As long as every element is related to at least one element a symmetric, transitive relation is reflexive.